# Input field not showing in ActiveAdmin nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

[image]Hi i have two models named Search_result and sharing_type .I have used has_many assocition between the two models.
in my search_result.rb

```
class SearchResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sharing_types ,dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sharing_types, allow_destroy: true
end
```

in my sharing_type.rb i have defined as

```
class SharingType < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :search_result
 end
```

in my ActiveAdmin

```
ActiveAdmin.register SearchResult do

 permit_params:gender,:postdate:location_cd,:location_name,
sharing_types_attributes: [:id, :typename ]
form multipart: true  do |f|
    f.input :gender
    f.input :postdate, :required => false
    f.input :location_cd, :required => false, :label => "Location Code"
    f.input :location_name, :required => false, :label => "Location Name"
    f.inputs "sharing_types" do
      f.has_many :sharing_types, allow_destroy: true do |cf|
        cf.input :typename 
      end
    end
     f.actions
 end
end
```

while in my active admin view no input field for typename is showing .

Comment: Please post strong parameters in controller

Comment: which controller , i am using ActiveAdmin in which strong parameters are in .rb file